# Nexus repository "create" privilege

Tags: nexus, privileges

I tried with no success to create a custom role with : Repositories - `create`, `read` privilege

When I login as a user with this role i can see the little green "add" in the repository UI in Nexus.

When I try to click on it I get an error:

```
There is an error communicating with the server.type Rapport d'état
Nexus returned an error: ERROR 403: Interdit
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "views/repositories - system feeds - authentication and authorization feed" in the UI, this will show you what is missing.

In this case, the problem is likely that you need to add the "repository templates (read)" privilege.

Comment: thank you , it's work perferctly, now my user can create repository but can't change configuration of an existing repository, exactly what I want.